# WebClient filters doOnNext called in reverse order

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to understand how doOnNext for ExchangeFilterFunctions are being called.
I extended this code https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-reactive-rest-service
to do this

```
@Component
public class GreetingClient {

    private final WebClient client;

    // Spring Boot auto-configures a `WebClient.Builder` instance with nice defaults and customizations.
    // We can use it to create a dedicated `WebClient` for our component.
    public GreetingClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        this.client = builder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .filter(filter1)
                .filter(filter2)
                .build();
    }

    public Mono<String> getMessage() {
        return this.client.get().uri("/hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Greeting.class)
                .map(Greeting::getMessage);
    }

    ExchangeFilterFunction filter1 = ((clientRequest, exchangeFunction) -> {
        System.out.println("Filter1 invoked");
        return exchangeFunction.exchange(clientRequest).doOnNext(
                clientResponse -> {
                    System.out.println("doOnNext for filter1");
                }
        );
    });

    ExchangeFilterFunction filter2 = ((clientRequest, exchangeFunction) -> {
        System.out.println("Filter2 invoked");
        return exchangeFunction.exchange(clientRequest).doOnNext(
                clientResponse -> {
                    System.out.println("doOnNext for filter2");
                }
        );
    });
}
```

## The Output

```
Filter1 invoked
Filter2 invoked
doOnNext for filter2
doOnNext for filter1
>> message = Hello, Spring!
```

**The filter1 is invoked after filter2 but doOnNext is invoked in the reverse order.** I read this discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20216 & the fix was done for WebClientBuilder to execute filters in the order they are added.

Not sure what I am missing.